Understanding complex generic types and function return types
I'm working with TypeScript and trying to understand how to properly use complex generic types and function return types. I have the following code:
interface Example<
  Arg0,
  Arg1 extends (payload: ReturnType<Arg2>) => Arg0,
  Arg2 extends (payload: ReturnType<Arg3>) => any,
  Arg3 extends (...arg: any) => any
> {
  func: Arg1;
  func2: Arg2;
  func3: Arg3;
}

function test<
  T extends Example<Arg0, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3>,
  Arg0 = ReturnType<T["func"]>,
  Arg1 extends (payload: ReturnType<Arg2>) => any = T["func"],
  Arg2 extends (payload: ReturnType<Arg3>) => any = T["func2"],
  Arg3 extends (...arg: any) => any = T["func3"]
>(arg: Readonly<T>): Arg0 {
  return {} as any;
}

test({
  func: (payload) => 1, // the payload equal any, expect equal { test: number }
  func2: (payload) => {
    // the payload equal { test: string }, is correct
    return { test: 1 };
  },
  func3: () => {
    return { test: "string" };
  },
}); // the return value equal type number, is correct

function test2<
  Arg0,
  Arg1 extends (payload: ReturnType<Arg2>) => Arg0,
  Arg2 extends (payload: ReturnType<Arg3>) => any,
  Arg3 extends (...arg: any) => any
>(arg: Example<Arg0, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3>): Arg0 {
  return {} as any;
}

test2({
  func: (payload) => 1, // the payload equal any, expect equal { test: number }
  func2: (payload) => {
    // the payload equal { test: string }, is correct
    return { test: 1 };
  },
  func3: () => {
    return { test: "string" };
  },
}); // the return value equal type unknown, expect equal number

I'm having trouble understanding the following:

In the test function, the payload for func is any, but I expect it to be { test: number }. How can I enforce this?
In the test2 function, the return value is unknown, but I expect it to be number. How can I ensure the return type is number?


Neither function is particularly well-conditioned to work with TS's inference. You are trying to do simultaneous inference of generic type arguments and callback parameters, in a single object. This is hard for TS to do even in the best of circumstances: see ms/TS#47599. (see next comment)

(see prev comment) If you want things to work, you should refactor to use more straightforward types (use the arg/return types as type params, not the whole function type) and put your object literal properties in order of inference (func3 first, etc) as shown in this playground link and described in the TS4.7 release notes. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up a full answer post; if not, what am I missing?

Thanks you for reply, but about case property func3 is optional property, i want to know the property is set or not. if using the sample in the playgound is only get the return of the func3, it don't care about func3 is set or not

I don’t see func3 being optional in your question; did I miss it?
